# Fast Growing Shade Tree

Tags: trees, shade, desert

We're buying a house in the desert southwest (US) and want to plant a shade tree to cast shade over the western aspect of the home.  I like oak trees but want to get the house shaded sooner rather than later!

The tree will sit in the middle of a watered yard so it will have a consistent source of water.  The elevation is ~1500' / 450m above sea level and temps can range from the high 20°F - 120°F (-7°C - 49°C) at the extremes.  We have sun, or minimal clouds, 330 days a year.

We want a tree that does not drop seed pods, fruit, or excessive pollen.  Leaves are fine.  We also want to avoid eucalyptus and pine.

I'm left with Arizona Ash or Sissoo trees...that I know of.  Both of these are common in our area.  What else might work?